# An inequality in product space $V$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, banach-spaces, inequalities, euclidean-geometry

**I found an inequality as following:** Let $x, y, z$ be three complex numbers then:

\begin{equation*} \frac{1}{2}(|y+z-x|+|x+z-y| + |y+x-z|) \le |x| + |y|+|z|+\frac{1}{2}|x+y+z| \end{equation*} (1)

The inequality holds with equality if and only if $x+y+z=0$

**Note that:** *I have a proof of the inequality (1).*

> **My question:** I am looking for a proof of conjecture as following:
>
> Let $x, y, z$ in an inner product space $V$ then
>
> \begin{equation*}\frac{1}{2}(\|y+z-x\|+\|x+z-y\| + \|y+x-z\|) \le \|x\| + \|y\|+\|z\|+\frac{1}{2}\|x+y+z\|\end{equation*}
>
> where the norm ||z|| denotes the norm induced by the inner product

**See also**

- [Hlawka's inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HlawkasInequality.html)
- [Absolute value inequality for complex numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167685/absolute-value-inequality-for-complex-numbers/167741#167741)

Comment: So what if you take $x=1$ and $y=z=0$? If you put $3/2$ before the norms of single elements, on the right of the inequality, then it follows from Hlawka's inequality and the triangle inequality, after an appropriate change of variables.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Thank to You , I am going to check and edit

Comment: @FernandoMuro, I corrected

Comment: I don't think this helps. You already claimed to have a proof for the previous obviously false formula. I think you should provide your temptative prove and move this question to MathSackExchange.

Comment: Dear @FernandoMuro Please waiting me, I will post the proof in here. Because The original version is true. I don't want to post original formula, so I equivalent change (<=>) to new formula, but my change is false.  But now the formula is correct because I checked my changes process

Comment: Also, my version, pointed at in the top comment, is sharper than yours.

Comment: @FernandoMuro You mean, the inequality can be prove by Hlawka's inequality? or please post the your version in next comment.

Comment: @FernandoMuro My original inequality here: 

$|x|+|y|+|z|\leq |z+y|+|x+z|+|y+x|+|x+y+z|$

Comment: I don't know why the [same topic](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167685/absolute-value-inequality-for-complex-numbers/167741#167741) is many vote up. But this topic is close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the 1-dimensional case which you say is true: project everything to a randomly chosen line, apply 1d case and integrate.

Comment: I will posted the proof in nex some days. Thank to You very much.

Comment: I don't know why the [same topic](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167685/absolute-value-inequality-for-complex-numbers/167741#167741) is many vote up. But this is close topic.